# file get contents request 400 graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, file-get-contents

When I do a request with file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) I get this result back.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

But when I copy the url in my browser it works, anyone any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(['http'=>['ignore_errors' => true]]);
$data = file_get_contents($url, 0 , $ctx);
```

for http answer codes differrents from 200.

ps: array syntax for 5.4; change [ ... ] to array( ... ) if you use <5.4